# $http post request is not adding specified headers

Tags: angularjs, cors, jetty, preflight, jetty-8

I am making request to my server using $http to my backend for login purpose but even after specifying the headers properly its pre-flighting my request and also adding headers which I never asked it too.

This is the request that I make to the server

```
$http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost:8080/SignInMainServlet',
       data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
                login_source: source,
                accessToken: code,
                referrer_code: referral_id
            }),
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' }
     });
```

This is my server code to handle the request

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    REFERRAL_CODE_COUNT++;
    String referrer_code=request.getParameter("referrer_code");
    String login_source=request.getParameter("login_source");
    String accessToken=request.getParameter("accessToken");

    SignInMainManager m = new SignInMainManager(accessToken, referrer_code, login_source,REFERRAL_CODE_COUNT);
    String result = m.signIn();


    response.setContentType("text/html");  

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 


    out.println(result);
    out.close();//closing the stream 


}
```

This is the error the browser console shows

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/SignInMainServlet. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is how the request,response and general looks like on chrome for the xhr call

```
// Request//
OPTIONS /SignInMainServlet HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Mobile Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

//Response//
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Feb 2017 10:44:57 GMT
Allow: POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031)

//General//
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/SignInMainServlet
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
```

Stuck here since a day. Really need HELP!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using `authentification`. I belive your preflight request is not working cause you missed some configurations in your CORS. In that way your preflight request aborts. Setup your CORS like this:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization");
```

Most important is that you only configured a `protected void doPost()` listener. In that way the preflight `OPTIONS` request does not have CORS configured because its listening on `doOptions()`. Add a `doOptions()` listener and put your CORS configuration into it or define your `response` CORS globaly.

#### Somethink like that:

```
protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.close();//closing the stream
}
```

Comment: Why is  'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization' present in my request even though I never seemed to have applied it anywhere?

Comment: Its shown up in your response/request `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization`. Is this the request or response header?

Comment: But I never myself added it

Comment: The request header

Comment: Well, this could depend on the Header configuration in your client application or your client (browser) is manipulating the headers. Does this CORS setup work for you?

Comment: No bro it doesn't help

Comment: There are no extra header configurations as well

Comment: @S.Patel I think I found your problem. Take a look at the improved answer.